# Does JWT make any sense in CRUD applications?

Tags: database, rest, jwt, authorization, backend

Why would I use JWT instead of SessionID for example if I make a call to database in the same endpoint, just after confirming authorization for given user? It makes no sense to me in this case, it kinda loses the purpose.

I understand that the idea behind JWT is to eliminate a call to database, and thus make it more scalable and efficient. But if just after that I make a call to database, what's the point then?

With Session ID I would have two calls to db instead of cryptographic function calculation of JWT and then call to database.

So where is the advantage of JWT over Session ID? Or it just comes down to fact that CRUD endpoints, or just endpoints that talk to database are not the place where JWT shines, am I right here?

Answer (score 0):

JWT doesn't have a benefit over using sessions,JWTs provide a means of maintaining session state on the client instead of doing it on the server.

With server-side sessions, you will either have to store the session identifier in a database, or else keep it in memory and make sure that the client always hits the same server. Both of these have drawbacks. In the case of the database (or other centralizedstorage), this becomes a bottleneck and a thing to maintain - essentially an extra query to be done with every request. Session to the client means that you remove the dependency on a server-side session, but it imposes its own set of challenges.

Comment: I understand, but since a query is already sent to database (CRUD type app) what difference will it make? One SELECT from users table is at the worst case at the same computational complexity level (and similar delay to db etc.) compared with actual operation with data, with business logic. Database is contacted in every call whatever authorization mechanism I'm using, that's what my main point is.


Maybe this type of app is just not the right opportunity for JWT to shine